# Deconstructing pseudo instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

So we all know what pseudo instructions are. An operation which the assembler recognizes, but which will be deconstructed into 1 or more actual machine instructions.

I have been searching for, but cannot find a definitive source which explains exactly which machine instructions each pseudo instruction gets broken down into. Unless I am blind it is not explained in either "The MIPS32 Instruction Set" by Mips themselves, or in the Patterson/Hennessy book.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am only using MIPS 32 if it makes a difference.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#Pseudo_instructions

Comment: Ha! Would never have thought to check Wikipedia. Thank you!

Comment: It's literally the second hit when Googling for `MIPS pseudo instructions`.

Comment: Hence why I didn't find it. I was not searching online, I was searching the documentation which purports to define the entire instruction set. I've given up on online docs for MIPS because they are hit and miss, and generally assume you are using SPIM which I am not.